# Is it possible to view set bonus without collecting entire set?

Tags: the-surge

I'm asking about seeing set bonus in game, no in wiki.

I can see it once I complete the set on stats page, but is it possible to see set bonus having only some pieces or even recipes? I'm quite early in the game and crafting all the sets just to see their bonuses is too expensive. I play on PS4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been playing through the game again to get the full experience going into The Surge 2. I wondered this question myself when I was a few hours in. From my own experimenting, there is no way to see the full bonus in game without building and equipping the entire armor set (1 headpiece, 1 chest piece, 2 arms, and 2 legs).

Comment: yes, I came to the same conclusion after multiple playthroughs. I hope they added it in The Surge 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an exception regarding the head - you can wear the sunglasses or the mascot head instead of the regular rig set piece and still receive the bonus as if you had the whole set on.